# Are the elementary predictable processes dense in $L^2([M])$ for $M$ a local martingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The question is the one from the title. I know this is true when $M$ is an $L^2$ bounded martingale (which is often used in the classical approach to the construction of the stochastic integral) but I'm not sure about the local martingale case.